# How to call onCreateOptionsMenu from code

Tags: java, android

I want to call onCreateOptionsMenu from the code because if i use:

```
menu.setGroupEnabled(0, false);
```

With:

```
public Menu menu;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    menu.add(0,0,0,"Option");
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't work if the user never pressed menu button. How can I do that?

Thanks

PS: If this is a bad practice let me know

Answer (score 14):

I believe you want `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Doesn't work... throws nullpointerexception when i use menu.setGroupEnabled(0, false);

Comment: what is the minimum SDK you are using?

Comment: from the docs is says `You can safely hold on to menu (and any items created from it), making modifications to it as desired, until the next time onCreateOptionsMenu() is called.` meaning you shouldnt have to go back to that method if you want to chenge something in the menu

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean

Comment: meaning you already have a reference to the current menu...so just use it whenever you want...

Comment: but as i said if the user does not call menu button it wont work